# How to embed or link google sheets to docs?

Tags: google-sheets, hyperlink, formatting, embed, google-docs

I need to embed sheets to docs so what I change in sheets gets changed over to docs. I can do it by copying the table in the sheet and pasting it in docs and select the 'link to spreadsheet', the doc gets changed when I click 'update' over the table.

However, if I make a copy of both files and move them, the doc's link is still with the original sheet. The sheet I copied and moved does not do anything.

If there any way to copy both files and keeping all the formatting and links so I can have backups and not rely on one master sheet storing all the tables?

Or how can I manually 'link' the copied sheet to the copied docs without going through copying and pasting all the individual tables?

Thanks
Alex